# How to exclude a specific package of a jar dependency in Grails project?

Tags: grails, dependencies

In my Grails project, I used library A. One of A's dependencies is B. In B jar, there's a package (named C) that I want to exclude from my project (because it duplicates an existing package in JDK and causes error when starting up the application). But I don't know the correct syntax to do this. I tried the below codes but it does not work

```
dependencies {  
     runtime ('A-library') {  
            excludes(<what-I-should-write-here>)  
     }
}
```

Could you please help me on this? Thank you so much

Comment: Usage of a 'delete' method in BuildConfig is suggested here (I don't offer it as an answer because I have never tried it myself): http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-exclude-mail-jar-and-activation-jar-from-Mail-plugin-td2336346.html

Perhaps that doesn't help you unless you're building and running a .war.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how it works. Dependency management works on jar files (and plugins), not classes or packages. If you need to exclude a class or package you need to specify a different version that doesn't include them, or if necessary rebuild the jar yourself with those classes removed.

Answer (score 5):

You can only include/exclude B completely, you can't include/exclude certain packages of B. To achieve your goal you would need to find (or create) a modified version of B that has the duplicate packages removed. Then change your `BuildConfig.groovy` to:

```
dependencies {  
     runtime ('A-library') {  
            excludes('B-library')  
     }
     runtime 'B-library-with-duplicate-packages-excluded'
}
```